# How can an MQTT-SN Gateway differentiate the same topic ID from different publishing clients to deliver to the subscriber?

Tags: mqtt

I understand that in MQTT-SN instead of the long House/3rdFloor/Bedroom/Bed/Temperature topic name for every publishing like in MQTT, we REGISTER the Publisher to the Gateway at first and get in the REGACK a very short topic ID instead, like *001F*, which the Publisher shall use to send the information (temperature) back to be received by subscriber.

(Of course, we need to configure the gateway first to have all those naming)

But say I have a second sensor, connected through the same method (wifi, Zigbee router etc) and it's supposed to be House/2ndFloor/Bedroom/Bed/Temperature topic. And we get this short topic ID of *001F* as well to PUBLISH the information.

tl;dr**How can the gateway not get this mixed up?**

Let me check my understanding here and elaborate more...I have my publishing sensors as MQclient 1 at 3rdFloor and MQclient 2 at 2ndFloor, The data shall be displayed in a subscribing website which will gather the information from the broker as well, and we'll call this MQclientweb.

This MQclientweb has the House/2ndFloor/Bedroom/Bed/Temperature or House/3rdFloor/Bedroom/Bed/Temperature topic names configured with the gateway, so not really an issue, and I can't reconfigure the name as well.

MQclient 1 and 2 CONNECTs to the Gateway and REGISTERs to get their topic IDs, which are identical to each other (001F), and finally they start to send information.

Is there a unique connection that is maintained to be alive, so even though the topic ID is the same, the gateway can direct it correctly? Like the equivalent of local ports in web browsers, but at the Gateway side?

Comment: There is no reason the broker can not be keeping the topic mapping on a per client id basis

Comment: So you're saying that in MQTT-SN's case, the broker has been preset (or has to be preset) to have both the client mapping and the topic mapping set, in which case it has saved the MQClient1 and MQClient2 as a distinctive client (publisher) ID.

Does this mean that from the client (equivalent of MQTT.fx for PC for example) it's not possible to create or delete the client list without accessing the broker directly?

Comment: Why would the gateway assign the same ID to different topics?